# How to set up a base station without known coordinates

Tags: 3d, land-survey, base-station

I am new to surveying, but need to set up a Topcon controller with Pocket 3-D to run 2 receivers and a grader running off the base receiver for my new job. It sounds stupid, because I can't seem to find an answer anywhere, but how do I set up my base station? If the area has never been surveyed before, then there are no known coordinates to use. I've considered setting up the base receiver and telling it to log data for a couple hours (using a GR-5 model receiver), sucking the data off the internal disk and putting it on the computer. Then I could use something like OPUS to get differential corrections, giving me some sort of accurate point to use for base coordinates. I have no idea if this would work, and have barely any access to the equipment. I'm trying to make a game plan for when I have a chance to tinker with the system. Does this make sense or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What country are you in? In the US (and some other locations around the world) the CORS network can be used ([link](http://geodesy.noaa.gov/CORS/))

Comment: The U.S., Kansas. I need to give my boss a plan of attack on how I plan to start surveying his company's land, and am trying to work out the kinks of DGPS. If I can find a county survey marker nearby I shouldn't need to use that though, correct?

Comment: Yes, if you can find a nearby survey marker to start from and work your way into unsurveyed land, that should be fine -- as long as you aren't in some extreme never-surveyed-anywhere wilderness area. (I don't expect Kansas would have much of that...)

Comment: thank you so much, i thought surveying would be easier, but i didn't do much in college, was more social geography